# Some text is not showing in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

A few days ago I noticed something changed (for the worse) in my PyCharm.

Some of the text that I have in files is no longer visible. The only way to view it is to double clock the space where the text is and then its highlighted. Otherwise I can not see the text.

This affects all file types in my PyCharm including `.yml` and `.py`.

This is the code inside the file:

```
    something:
      new 1: {try: fail}
      old three: {again: no}
      interesting and: {box: none}
```

and this is what I see:

[image]

Does anyone know what is causing this issue? I looked around and was unable to find a way to fix this.

Comment: Try switching to another theme (the editor colors, not the GUI), e.g. to a default light one? Will it show there? If it does: switch again to your Darcula -- it is still the same? If you have modified some colors, try switching to a bundled Darcula.

Comment: @LazyOne that did not work but restarting it did. But thats not always the case :(

Comment: @LazyOne it happened again so I changed the scheme colors from Darcula to Default and it solved the problem. I tried switching to Darcula again and its still messed up. Any idea why Darcula sometimes works and sometimes doesn't?

Btw what is bundled Darcula?

acrtually it still looks bad with the darker themes...seems only Default and WarmNeon fix the problem

Comment: "Bundled" means the one that comes with the IDE -- the original/unmodified scheme. "your Darcula" is the original Darcula with your changes on top.

Comment: I do not know why it work one day and break on another. My only guesses: 1) you are using some settings Sync plugin (the IDE comes with 2 of such plugins actually) and the Sync is happening across different OS (e.g. work Windows machine and home Linux). This may cause some issues (in theory at very least) 2) Maybe you are using a setup where the IDE uses your OS theme (e.g. light during the day and Dark after sunset etc) and that somehow causes issues. 3) You have some theme-related plugin that somehow misbehaves and causes this issue.

Comment: I may suggest to contact JetBrains Support Team (can be done right from the ID -- `Help | Contact Support`) -- they should have a better ideas on how their software works (bigger database of issues and how it may be resolved).

Comment: thanks @LazyOne...what do you mean by "done right from the ID"? sorry still a bit new...

edit: nvm i think you meant IDE - found the support :)

Comment: It should have been "IDE" there. "can be done right from the **IDE**". PyCharm Main Menu --> Help --> Contact Support (or whatever the correct name for the action is to make a **Support Ticket** (NOT the Issue Tracker ticket).